# Cannot Query MongoDB API using HTTP’s requests

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, https

i am trying to query the MongoDB API using a API key as the authentication method, but I keep getting the 401 status code.

Here is the code:

```
fetch(‘https://eu-west-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/application-0-dhdvm/endpoint/mydatabase’, {
method: ‘GET’,
mode: ‘cors’,
cache: ‘no-cache’,
headers: {
‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’,
‘Authorization’: Bearer ${apiKey}, // Include your API key in the Authorization header
},
})
```

I generated the API KEY:

[image: myAPIkey]

(I exported the key value before it was created so thats not the problem)

Here is the endpoint I created:

[image: EndPoint]

Please I need help, somehow I am not able to query the database correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Data API does not use `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>`.   The docs at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/examples/ have examples like this; note the `api-key` header:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://us-east-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-paviu/endpoint/data/v1/action/find' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' \
--header 'api-key: <YourApiKey>' \
--data-raw '{
    "collection":"foo",
    "database":"testX",
    "dataSource":"test0",
    "projection": {"_id": 1}
}
```

Try running `curl` from the command line to verify that your endpoints and API keys are working, then step forward and get it running in a code environment.